# write where clause query in MySQL from comma separated IDs

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have bunch blog posts in my posts table. Suppose,

```
+----+----------------------+-------------------------+
| id | title                | categories              | 
+----+----------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | title 1              | 234, 235, 243           | 
| 2  | title 2              | 237                     |
| 2  | title 3              | 234, 243                |
+----+----------------------+-------------------------+
```

Now, I am trying to select all of posts where categories 243. I already tried to use `FIND_IN_SET` function which can select posts if id is the first number in categories field.

My Current Query is like this-
`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(235, Category) <> 0 ORDER BY PostId DESC`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHERE FIND_IN_SET(243,Category) should work.

Comment: Are you sure you typed correct column name? `FIND_IN_SET(235, categories)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know how bad an idea it is to store categories in such a list.  Here are some reasons:

- Storing numbers as strings is bad.
- SQL has relatively poor string manipulation functions.
- The resulting queries cannot use indexes.
- Foreign key constraints cannot be declared.

So, you should fix the data to use a junction table.

Sometimes, we are struck with other peoples bad design decisions.

In this case, the problem would see to be the spaces in the list.  Try this:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(235, replace(Category, ' ', '') > 0
```

Or, alternatively:

```
WHERE CONCAT(', ', 235, ', ') LIKE CONCAT('%, ', Category, ', %')
```

However, I would encourage you to use relational data structures correctly and implement a junction table.

Comment: great.works fine. :) I am trying but you have given answer before me and better than mine.

Comment: awesome solution. appreciate it.